# How can I dispatch a state change to redux when calling it from a function inside the component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm still fairly new to Javascript and React, and have been trying to introduce Redux into my admin-site project.

Right now the only thing I want to use it for is to change the ip-address of all `axios` calls to my backend. So on my admin site, when the user goes to log in, they will be presented with a drop-down of different servers that the site can make a request to, e.g. development, staging, production...

So when the user does log in, any component that needs to make a request, which is actually every single component, can use the IP-address that is stored in the redux state.

A kind of mini-question is I see a lot of people recommend not to `connect` all components to the redux `store`, but never sure why, for this, should I just put the IP-address in local-storage and `clear()` it everytime the user tries to log in? Anyway, I want to at least successfully implement Redux so I can use it in the future if need be.

The problem is that I have some `buttons`, which DO successfully change the state in the redux-store, and then other components once logged in make the requests to that particular server. But in the dropdown I just put in `<Select   />`,  upon any change, it then calls a function inside my component, the function runs and everything gets logged to console as it should, EXCEPT that the state in the redux-store doesnt change anymore, but as I can see it, its still using the same call to react-redux `connect` as the `buttons` were doing

So I have my `actions.js`:

```
export const DEV_ADDRESS = 'dev.example.com';
export const STAGE_ADDRESS = 'stage.exmaple.com';
export const PROD_ADDRESS = 'prod.example.com';

export function devServer() {
  return {
    type: DEV_ADDRESS,
  };
}

export function stageServer() {
  return {
    type: STAGE_ADDRESS,
  };
}

export function prodServer() {
  return {
    type: PROD_ADDRESS,
  };
}
```

And my `reducer.js`:

```
import {
  DEV_ADDRESS,
  STAGE_ADDRESS,
  PROD_ADDRESS,
} from '../actions/serverActions';

const initialState = {
  serverAddress: PROD_ADDRESS,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case DEV_ADDRESS:
      console.log("REDUCER DEV");
      return {
        ...state,
        serverAddress: DEV_ADDRESS
      };
    case STAGE_ADDRESS:
      console.log("REDUCER STAGE");
      return {
        ...state,
        serverAddress: STAGE_ADDRESS
      };
      case PROD_ADDRESS:
        console.log("REDUCER PROD");
        return {
          ...state,
          serverAddress: PROD_ADDRESS
        };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Now in my `LogIn.jsx`:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button } from 'reactstrap';
import axios from 'axios';
import Select from 'react-select';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import EyeIcon from 'mdi-react/EyeIcon';
import Logo from '../../shared/img/logo/logo_light_2.svg';
import * as serverActionTypes from '../../redux/actions/serverActions';


class LogIn extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showPassword: false,
      in: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    localStorage.clear();
  }

  .
  .
  .
  .
  .

  handleEmailChange(event) {
    this.setState({ email: event.target.value })
  }

  handlePasswordChange(event) {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value})

  handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$");
    console.log(selectedOption.value);
    console.log(this.props)
    if (selectedOption.value === serverActionTypes.devServer().type) {
      console.log("handle dev change");
      {this.props.onSelectDevServerAddress}
    }
    else if (selectedOption.value === serverActionTypes.stageServer().type) {
      console.log("handle stage change");
      {this.props.onSelectStageServerAddress}
    }
    else if (selectedOption.value === serverActionTypes.prodServer().type) {
      console.log("handle prod change");
      {this.props.onSelectProdServerAddress}
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    if (this.state.in === true) {
      return <Redirect to={{pathname: "/dashboard"}} />;
    }

    return (
      <div className="account">
        <div className="account__wrapper">
          <div className="account__card" align="center">
            <img
              src={Logo}
              alt="example-logo"
              height="35"
              style={{marginBottom: '50px'}}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="account__card">
            <form className="form form--horizontal" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <div className="form__form-group">
                <span className="form__form-group-label">E-mail</span>
                <div className="form__form-group-field">
                  <Field
                    name="email"
                    component="input"
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="example@mail.com"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChange={this.handleEmailChange.bind(this)}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form__form-group">
                <span className="form__form-group-label">Password</span>
                <div className="form__form-group-field">
                  <Field
                    name="password"
                    component="input"
                    type={this.state.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onChange={this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this)}
                  />
                  <button
                    className={`form__form-group-button${this.state.showPassword ? ' active' : ''}`}
                    onClick={e => this.showPassword(e)}
                  ><EyeIcon />
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="form__form-group">
                <span className="form__form-group-label">Server</span>
                <div className="form__form-group-field">
                  <div className="form__form-group-input-wrap">
                    <Select
                      name='server_address_selector'
                      value='prod.example.com'
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                      options={[
                        { value: 'dev.example.com', label: 'Dev' },
                        { value: 'stage.example.com', label: 'Stage' },
                        { value: 'prod.example.com', label: 'Prod' },
                      ]}
                      clearable={false}
                      className="form__form-group-select"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <Button
                color="success"
                onClick={this.onLogin.bind(this)}
                outline>
                Sign In
              </Button>
              <Button
                color="success"
                onClick={this.props.onSelectDevServerAddress}
                outline>
                DEV
              </Button>
              <Button
                color="success"
                onClick={this.props.onSelectStageServerAddress}
                outline>
                STAGE
              </Button>
              <Button
                color="success"
                onClick={this.props.onSelectProdServerAddress}
                outline>
                PROD
              </Button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    ipAddress: state.server
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onSelectDevServerAddress: () => dispatch(serverActionTypes.devServer()),
  onSelectStageServerAddress: () => dispatch(serverActionTypes.stageServer()),
  onSelectProdServerAddress: () => dispatch(serverActionTypes.prodServer()),
});

LogIn = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(LogIn);

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'log_in_form'
})(LogIn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't dispatch any action to the reducer. You have to actually invoke a functions from mapStateToDispatch in order to perform some update on the redux store state.

In the code below:

```
handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
console.log("$$$$$$$$$$$$");
console.log(selectedOption.value);
console.log(this.props)
if (selectedOption.value === serverActionTypes.devServer().type) {
  console.log("handle dev change");
  {this.props.onSelectDevServerAddress}
}
else if (selectedOption.value === serverActionTypes.stageServer().type) {
  console.log("handle stage change");
  {this.props.onSelectStageServerAddress}
}
else if (selectedOption.value === serverActionTypes.prodServer().type) {
  console.log("handle prod change");
  {this.props.onSelectProdServerAddress}
}
};
```

Instead of doing something like this:
    {this.props.onSelectProdServerAddress}

You have to call that function:
    this.props.onSelectProdServerAddress();

Now, your action will be dispatched to the reducer.

Comment: Such a simple solution, but with that working, how did redux update the state when calling `onClick` from the `<Button ../>`?

Comment: It work the same way, but in that case function is invoked by on click event. If you are familiar with DOM api you can imagine that React use function which you pass into the onClick prop in the way: window.addEventListener('click', this.props.onSelectProdServerAddress);